# Collapse/Expand Code Blocks

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2016

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016, how do i generate the "-" and "+" (like image below) to collapse/expand code blocks?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/code-outlining?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Begin End for the block of code

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/code-outlining?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any way to control it. Based on the lag time between opening a file and seeing the code folding/blocks appear, I think it's based on parsing the code and then creating foldable blocks based upon that analysis and SSMS knowing the syntax of SQL statements/queries.